# AVRDude not reading fuses in Eclipse with USB attached STK600

Tags: avr, avrdude

I can successfully burn programs using my USB connected STK600 through Eclipse/AVRDude.

From the command line, I can read fuses (using: `avrdude -px128a1 -Pusb -cstk600 -v`), but when I click "Read Fuses" from within AVREclipse/AVRDude I get the following error:

> Programmer "stk600" could not initialize the target hardware.
>
> Please Check that the target hardware is connected correctly
>
> Reason:
>
> avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1

Is this a bug or a setup problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the fuses in AVRStudio?

Comment: Yes -- they read just fine.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.